# How do i Setup utf-8 as standard character set for a mysql server?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, mysql

do i have to recompile it?

i figured out diffent ways of setting the character set values see

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset.html

but starting it with other values or my.cnf settings changed nothing. Because if i do:

sudo mysqld --verbose --help | grep charact

it always answers me latin1 as standard charset.
the system is ubuntu lts server with a standard mysql install.

Comment: which values did you try to change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution:

add this into my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets default-character-set=utf8

[mysqladmin]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets default-character-set=utf8

[mysqlcheck]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets default-character-set=utf8

[mysqldump]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets default-character-set=utf8

[mysqlimport]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets default-character-set=utf8

[mysqlshow]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets default-character-set=utf8
#end
```

Comment: if you just want to configure the server. just create a config file like so:

    _/etc/mysql/conf.d/utf8.cnf_
    
    [mysqld]
    character-set-server=utf8
    default-character-set=utf8

Comment: `default-character-set=utf8` It causes the server to not start, as the error what is saying on the logs.

Comment: It looks like default-character-set is no longer allowed in the [mysqld] section

Answer (score 5):

```
[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
skip-character-set-client-handshake

[client]
default-character-set   = utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set   = utf8
```

UPDATE: Nowadays you should probably use utf8mb4.

Answer (score 1):

Create file */etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld.cnf* with contents:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
```

If you omit *collation-server* it should be set up to *utf8_general_ci*.

I've tested this configuration with MySQL 5.6 on Ubuntu 15.04.