# Enabling UTF-8 character set in JSF2.0, Hibernate, MySQL

Tags: hibernate, jsf-2, utf-8, character-encoding, applicationcontext

We are to enable UTF-8 character encoding to our web application designed using JSF2.0, Hibernate, MySQL.

Following is the datasource defined in our application context file

```
<bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />   
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname" />  
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="useUnicode" value="yes" />
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
```

While running the application we are getting exception

```
Error creating bean with name 'SessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'DataSource'  Error creating bean with name 'DataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]: Invalid property 'useUnicode' of bean class [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Bean property 'useUnicode' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

We have also tried using the following but get an error

```
<bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />   
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8;" />  
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    </bean>


Error: The reference to entity "characterEncoding" must end with the ';' delimiter
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some work around I am able to handle the issue- Following is the code that is working for me to enable JDBC working with UTF8

```
<bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />   
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" />  
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    </bean>
```

Using `useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8` with `&amp;` served the purpose

To be able to use the same with Hibernate also specify the following to the hibernate properties

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>               
            </props>
        </property>
```

Specify request encoding format in the filter as well

```
public class ApplicationFilter implements Filter {    
        public void destroy() {
        }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        }

        public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        }
    }
```

Now even if your application and db are not supporting special characters check the database character set , try by recreating the database and using charset UTF8 instead latin1

Comment: That worked!. If using postgresqI had to do **set CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'UTF8'** in order to change the character encoding. Have a look at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/multibyte.html

Answer (score 0):

When you install MySQL with the UI installer, you can set the default character set as 'UTF-8'. After that everything works fine. I always set this at installation time so I don't know how to set it later. But if you don't want to reinstall MySQL, check this link:

[How do i Setup utf-8 as standard character set for a mysql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735758/how-do-i-setup-utf-8-as-standard-character-set-for-a-mysql-server)